# Downloading Canvas as JPG/PNG returns blank image

Tags: vue.js, svg, canvas, canvg

So, I'm using canvg and the function which converts svg file to a jpg/png just downloads and ignores id of a svg block element, so I get the blank image, what could be wrong? Maybe Vue does not support converting SVG to jpg/png using canvas.
Here is the javascript:

```
import canvg from "canvg";

 function SVG2PNG(svg, callback) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var w = 800;
  var h = 400;
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h; // Create a Canvas element.
  var ctx =  canvas.getContext("2d"); // For Canvas returns 2D graphic.
  debugger;
  var data = svg.outerHTML; // Get SVG element as HTML code.
  canvg.from(canvas, data); // Render SVG on Canvas.
  callback(canvas); // Execute callback function.
}

function generateLink(fileName, data) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = fileName;
  link.href = data;
  return link;
}

export default {
  methods: {
    tipka() {
        debugger;
      var element = document.getElementById("svg"); // Get SVG element.
      SVG2PNG(element, function (canvas) {
        // Arguments: SVG element, callback function.
        var base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // toDataURL return DataURI as Base64 format.
        generateLink("SVG2PNG-01.png", base64).click(); // Trigger the Link is made by Link Generator and download.
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Here is the ending of svg tag:
[image]
This is the start of svg tag:
[image]

Comment: (moving further clarifying questions from answer to question) Based on my experiments, it looks like a secondary problem might involve XML namespaces. Could you post the *opening* `<svg>` tag? Its attributes may be crucial here.

Comment: Sure, I added the opening `svg`, I think too that it might be the xml problem.

Comment: Here is the whole code of a shape converted in `svg` tag(it might be useful for a better testing): https://privatebin.net/?fc7e169a9d095029#3zh87Txmwidxb9zN1CJvTkAv6ETMJr7wqx7vrxeKYZDc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation for `Canvg.from`](https://canvg.github.io/canvg/classes/_src_canvg_.canvg.html#from), you need to pass it your drawing context, not the canvas itself. So change this line:

```js
canvg.from(canvas, data); // Render SVG on Canvas.
```

to:

```js
canvg.from(ctx, data); // Render SVG on Canvas.
```

It also appears, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61775465/html5-canvas-drawimage-not-working-on-firefox), that you will need to replace your `viewBox` attribute on the `<svg>` with `width` and `height` attributes, like:

```xml
<svg class="shape" version="1.1" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="400" height="400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 400 400;" xml:space="preserve">
```

You can then actually bypass canvg entirely with the function rewritten like this:

```js
function SVG2PNG(svg, callback) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400; // Create a Canvas element.
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // For Canvas returns 2D graphic.
    var svgString = svg.outerHTML;
    var img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 400);
        callback(canvas.toDataURL("image/png")); // toDataURL return DataURI as Base64 format.
    });
    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + svgString;
}
```

(Note that it now returns the data URL, not the canvas.)

Comment: I tried and it still does the same (downloads the blank image), is this maybe problem with vue? It's like that the svg element is being ignored...

Comment: Doubtful that Vue would have anything to do with this if the SVG is actually present on your page before this code runs. What does the `data` variable contain after it is initialized in `SVG2PNG`?

Comment: Maybe canvas does not support svg block tags. After its initialisation in the method variable data contains the whole svg code which I want to turn in image.

Comment: Well I'm not sure about the `canvg` library's limitations, but if you have the whole SVG already, you should be able to load it into an `HTMLImageElement` and pass it directly to [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) without needing any special library.

Comment: Can you show this in your answer? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Sure, for that we just need to look a little more broadly: where is the `<svg>` element coming from and how is it put on the page? It will probably be easier to pull the data one or two steps earlier than the `<svg>` element itself for this purpose.

Comment: Well that svg consists of few paths which are converted in a drawing (vectorized graphics), and after the `</svg>` there is the button which calls for function called: `tipka()`

Comment: I edited my question and put a screenshot how that svg looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233766/discussion-between-kdau-and-jan-tudan).